# How to display the values from one partial view control(Search) to a web grid partial view control?

Tags: razor

In my view i have two partial views (Search,webgrid). When i click the update button in the search , the values filtered are not binding in the webgrid ? How can i do this?

Comment: could you provide more info? e.g. some code of the views (partials and mainview) and the controller(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Hope I understood your question correctly.

search partial:

```
 ...
 @using(Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "SearchResults", 
 HttpMethod = "post" InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace})){
     <input id="searchString" type="text" value="Search for this ..." />
     <input type="submit" value="Search" />

 }
 ...
```

controller:

```
  [HttpPost]      
  public PartialViewResult Search(string searchString){
       IList<Results> results = _service.Search(searchString);
       return new PartialView("Webgrid", results)
  }
```

webgrid partial:

```
 @Model IList<Result>

 <div id="SearchResults">

 // Display Results

 </div>
```

Didn't compile the code. Hope it is almost compileable.